# How to set onClick listener for an ImageButton in ViewBinder?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I made a `ListView` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and a `ViewBinder` to set views for it, and I want to put an `ImageButton` in the `ViewBinder` but don't know how to set the `onClick` event. Should I create a `MySimpleCursorAdapter` and put it there or should I write it in the `ViewBinder` class?

Here is my code:

**ViewBinder.java**:

```
public class ChannelViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

                if(view instanceof ImageView) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                        byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));
                        return true;
                }

                if(view instanceof ImageButton) {
                        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view;
                        ib.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {     
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) { 
                                String dblink = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChannelDB.KEY_DBLINK));
                                Intent intent = new Intent();

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("dblink",dblink);
                                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                }
                            });

                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

and `ChannelPoster.java` representing an entry in the ListView`:

```
public class ChannelPoster {
    private Bitmap poster;
    private String channel;
    private String path;
    private String dblink;

    public ChannelPoster(Bitmap pi, String c, String p, String d) {
        poster = pi;
        channel = c;
        path = p;
        dblink = d;
    }

    public Bitmap getPoster() { return poster; }
    public String getChannel() { return channel; }
    public String getPath() { return path; }
    public String getDBlink() { return dblink; }
}
```

and `ChannelDB.java` the database one, I only post the concerning part:

```
public void createchannelEntry(ChannelPoster channel) {
        openDB();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channel.getPoster().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_POSTER, out.toByteArray());            
        cv.put(KEY_CHANNEL, channel.getChannel());
        cv.put(KEY_DBLINK, channel.getDBlink());
        cv.put(KEY_PATH, channel.getPath());
        mDb.insert(channelS_TABLE, null, cv);
        closeDB();
    }
```

and finally the list, `Tv.java`:

```
ListView channellist = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mDB = new ChannelDB(this);

        String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
        String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;

        Cursor c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.channelview,
                c,
                new String[] {mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_DBLINK},
                new int[] {R.id.poster, R.id.channel, R.id.douban});

        adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder());

        channellist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is how I add an entry if it helps:

```
  mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(image, "name" ,"link"  ,"link" ));
```

If you need more code just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Scratch my previous answer.  There was a bug when scrolling down after toggling the favorite star on a row.  I guess it has to do with how the views are being recycled or something.

Instead, I still pass my SQLite column `favorite` in the `from`, and the `resource id` of the star `ImageView` in the `to`.  Then I `extend SimpleCursorAdapter`, and `@Override bindView`.  I call the `super`, then get a handle to the `ImageView` using `view.findViewById`, with `view` being one of the parameters passed into `bindView`.  Using that handle I was able to conditionally set the appropriate drawable (star filled or unfilled), and set the `clickListener`.

**Original answer:**

My case is simpler, but similar, so I'll post what I did.  I needed a star that would allow the user to favorite a row, so I used an `ImageView`.  In my `from` I pass the SQLite column `favorite`, and in my `to` I pass the `resource Id` of the `ImageView`.

In my `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()`, which I added using `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder`, I overrode `setViewValue`.  I then use `cursor.getColumnIndex("favorite")` to test against the `index` value passed into `setViewValue`.  If equal, I set a `click listener` to the `view` parameter passed into `setViewValue`.  Depending on the value of `favorite` in my database, I toggle the `ImageView` appropriately, using `((ImageView) view).setImageResource()`.  I then, still in the listener, update the value in the database (personally using OrmLite).

Not exactly how I wanted to do it, but easier than extending CursorAdapter and handling everything myself, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend the SimpleCursorAdapter, you can place the onClick event inside your ViewBinder class. Here is how I did it:

```
private class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder 
{
 @Override
 public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) 
 {              
      if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_CUSTOM)) 
      {
          // If the column is COLUMN_NAME_CUSTOM then we use custom view.
          // The following two lines are needed so that you can still click 
          // elsewhere in the list row to select it
          view.setFocusable(false);
          view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
          // Set your onClickListener
          view.setOnClickListener(new  MyListener(someArgument)); 

          return true;
       }
       // For other columns, simply return false so that the default binding happens.
       return false;
   }

   // Define your onclicklistener           
   private class MyListener implements OnClickListener 
   {
        private String someArg = null;

         // Constructor that lets you pass an argument to the listener
         public MyListener(String someArg){
            this.someArg = someArg;
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            //Handle your click event here
         }
    }
}
```